# Laravel model event does not fire

Tags: php, laravel

I've made a custom trait in laravel 5.4 so when a pivot table is being `->sync();` it will fire an update event and then I will listen to that with an observer.

However it's not working the way I want.

In my app service provider:

```
Organisation::observe(OrganisationObserver::class);
```

There I've got this:

```
/**
 * Listen to the Organisation updated event.
 *
 * @param Organisation $organisation
 * @return void
 */
public function updated(Organisation $organisation)
{
    dd('test');
    $this->cache->tags(Organisation::class)->flush();
    $this->cache->tags(Relation::class)->flush();
}
```

THis is the trait I use on the model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Deal\Custom;

trait BelongsToManyWithSyncEvent
{
    /**
     * Custom belongs to many because by default it does not observes
     * changes on pivot tables. When a pivot table is changed return
     * a custom belongs to many with sync cache clear class.
     * Here we will clear the cache.
     *
     * @param $related
     * @param null $table
     * @param null $foreignKey
     * @param null $relatedKey
     * @param null $relation
     * @return BelongsToManyWithSyncCacheClear
     */
    public function belongsToMany($related, $table = null, $foreignKey = null, $relatedKey = null, $relation = null)
    {
        if (is_null($relation)) {
            $relation = $this->guessBelongsToManyRelation();
        }

        $instance = $this->newRelatedInstance($related);
        $foreignKey = $foreignKey ?: $this->getForeignKey();
        $relatedKey = $relatedKey ?: $instance->getForeignKey();

        if (is_null($table)) {
            $table = $this->joiningTable($related);
        }

        return new BelongsToManyWithSyncCacheClear(
            $instance->newQuery(), $this, $table, $foreignKey, $relatedKey, $relation
        );
    }
}
```

The `BelongsToManyWithSyncCacheClear` class looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Deal\Custom;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasEvents;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

class BelongsToManyWithSyncCacheClear extends BelongsToMany
{
    use HasEvents;

    /**
     * BelongsToManyWithSyncEvents constructor.
     *
     * @param Builder $query
     * @param Model $parent
     * @param string $table
     * @param string $foreignKey
     * @param string $relatedKey
     * @param null $relationName
     */
    public function __construct(Builder $query, Model $parent, $table, $foreignKey, $relatedKey, $relationName = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($query, $parent, $table, $foreignKey, $relatedKey, $relationName);
    }

    /**
     * When a pivot table is being synced,
     * we will clear the cache.
     *
     * @param array|\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|\Illuminate\Support\Collection $ids
     * @param bool $detaching
     * @return array
     */
    public function sync($ids, $detaching = true)
    {
        $changes = parent::sync($ids, $detaching);

        $this->fireModelEvent('updated', false);

        return $changes;
    }
}
```

Here I fire an updated event:

```
$this->fireModelEvent('updated', false);
```

But the `dd('test');` in my `OrganisationObserver` is never triggered. What am I doing wrong here!?